# vmware using proxy vpn to perform apt-get is invalid

Tags: networking, apt, vmware, proxy

I'm not using v2rayN proxy tool to execute my sh script in vmware ubuntu
Each time apt-get is executed,always returns "400 bad request",
But I copied the error link, and on my windows computer, it was always correct.
Similarly, I use the following ways to proxy,tool is v2rayN and core is the Xray.

We are using a mirror source.

Set /etc/apt/apt.conf:
Acquire::http::proxy "http://192.168.124.6:10804";
Set http_proxy & https_proxy
export http_proxy=http://192.168.124.6:10804
export https_proxy=socks5://192.168.124.6:10803
apt-get fails in both cases

However,I'm not use an v2rayN or I can change the closest mirror source to me and perform apt-get successfully, but I prefer to use the official mirror source.
Does anyone know how I should set up my proxy?thank you very much.

Also, I noticed the same problem on WSL.